# DistutilsExtra problem

Tags: python, django

I have installed Python 2.7, `setuptools` and `python-distutils-extra`.

When I try to run `./setup.py` build to compile C I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 26, in <module>
    from DistUtilsExtra.command import *
ImportError: No module named DistUtilsExtra.command
```

I beleive it has something to do with paths, but I am fairly new to Linux OS.

I am working on source `/opt/project_name/bin/activate`. It is a Django project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this page](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2012-December/128715.html), it is suggested to install python-apt through aptitude itself:

```
sudo apt-get install python-apt
```

Answer (score 4):

nowadays (2020) it is this (Python v2):

```bsh
sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra
```

or this (Python v3):

```bsh
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils-extra
```

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: On openSUSE: sudo zypper install python38-distutils-extra